# Problem with epsilon for Levi-Civita

Tags: support, mathjax

Is this the correct use for the Levi-Civita symbol:

\mathcal{E}_ijk

The lowercase "i" looks a bit off to me: $ \mathcal{E}_ijk $

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) the use `\varepsilon_{ijk}` when they write, for example: In three dimensions, the Levi-Civita symbol is defined by
$$\varepsilon_{ijk} =
  \begin{cases}
         +1 & \text{if } (i,j,k) \text{ is } (1,2,3), (2,3,1), \text{ or } (3,1,2), \\
         -1 & \text{if } (i,j,k) \text{ is } (3,2,1), (1,3,2), \text{ or } (2,1,3), \\
    \;\;\,0 & \text{if } i = j, \text{ or } j = k, \text{ or } k = i
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Bonus tip: If you highlight the entire expression on WIkipedia and copy it into here, you basically get free MathJax.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt The expression is a picture in Wikipedia. How can I transform  picture to MathJax?

Comment: @miracle173 You should be able to copy the entire thing, the math formulas on Wikipedia are not made through images but LaTeX I believe.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I see now if one edits the question one can get the source code, and this is Latex.

Answer (score 5):

If what you want to put in the subscript is not just one symbol you need to contain everything in braces. In your example actually *only* $i$ is placed *correctly* as a subscript,  which is one reason the thing does not look as you want it to look.

You should write:`$\mathcal{E}_{ijk}$` for  $\mathcal{E}_{ijk}$

To highlight this note $\sum_{i=1}$ vs $\sum_i=1$  `$\sum_{i=1}$ vs $\sum_i=1$`

Yet, note that as pointed out by Martin the symbol $\mathcal{E}$ is not commonly used in this context, instead `$\varepsilon$` $\varepsilon$ is used, which is smaller than the capital E and thus the proportions relative to the  subcript $i$ are different.